# Call a React Function from inside Render

Tags: function, reactjs, render

I'm using this [table component](https://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/example.html) with radioboxes (Row selection(Single)) and I want to update the react state to the currently selected row.

A function called **onRowSelect** shows the row selected. To update the state to the row selected, I created a function called **showRow()**, which is called in onRowSelect. However, I keep getting  a this.showRow() is not a function error.

I'm using showRow() outside the render function because I need to update the state with the currently chosen row.

```
class ChooseRowExample extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state =({
        chosenRow:""
      });
    this.showRow = this.showRow.bind(this);
  }

  showRow(row, isSelected){
      console.log(row);
      //update state here 
  }


  render() {

    var selectRowProp = {
      mode: "radio",
      clickToSelect: true,
      bgColor: "#A7EC57",
      onSelect: onRowSelect
    };

    function onRowSelect(row, isSelected){
      this.showRow(row, isSelected);
    }


  return (  
    <div>
        <BootstrapTable data={person} search={true} selectRow={selectRowProp}>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="id" isKey={true}>Client #</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="name">Company</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="contact_name">Client Name</TableHeaderColumn>
        </BootstrapTable>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: just move onRowSelect outside of render, with the other functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this` within `onRowSelect` is not the instance of the component like you are expecting.

You can use an ES6 arrow function for a lexical `this` that will reference the component instance.

So instead of:

```
var selectRowProp = {
  mode: "radio",
  clickToSelect: true,
  bgColor: "#A7EC57",
  onSelect: onRowSelect
};

function onRowSelect(row, isSelected){
  this.showRow(row, isSelected);
}
```

You should be able to do this:

```
var selectRowProp = {
  mode: "radio",
  clickToSelect: true,
  bgColor: "#A7EC57",
  onSelect: (row, isSelected) => this.showRow(row, isSelected)
};
```

Or even simply the following as you have already bound `showRow` to the components context in the constructor :

```
var selectRowProp = {
  mode: "radio",
  clickToSelect: true,
  bgColor: "#A7EC57",
  onSelect: this.showRow
};
```

Here is a bit more of an expanation of how `this` works in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this